# parse array of objects sent from frontend in python Django backend

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I have a web app, backend using Django, frontend using normal HTML5.

I the frontend, I use axios to send an array of objects via POST request.

```
axios
({
    method: 'POST',
    url: test_url,
    data: {
        [{title:1, isbn:1234},{title:2, isbn:5678}]
    }
})
```

However, in the backend, I could not succeed in parsing the data send from frontend.

```
def test_url(request):
    body = request.body.decode("utf-8")
    json_acceptable_string = body.replace("'", "\"")
    d = json.loads(json_acceptable_string)
    title = d.get('title')
    ...
```

I got json decode error in the backend.

How could I easily parse the array of objects sent from frontend in python?

Comment: Replacing `"'"` makes not much sense, exactly why are you doing this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist

```
js
axios
({
    method: 'POST',
    url: test_url,
    data: {
        "array_list" : [{"title": 1, "isbn": 1234}, {"title": 2, "isbn": 5678}]
    }
})

python
def test_url(request):
    data = request.POST
    array = data.getlist('array_list')
```